# Physics fluid stimulation is not showing rendering tab or being rendered in one particular project

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, materials, fluid-simulation, linked-data

I am in a middle of project. I did some basic flame kind of Stimulation for my project. I can see that effect in object mode and material mode but not in rendered mode. So I created a new project. And linked every collection from my actual project. When I rendered new project. I can finally see the render. But unfortunately I couldn't get my original lighting from original project. So, can you please tell me why my fluid (fire) stimulation is showing in one project and not not showing in other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I accidentally turned off the volumes option in filter tab under view layer properties.

[image]

Comment: Could you describe the steps to turn it on, perhaps illustrate with a few screenshots

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem in uploading screenshot

Here is the link of the screenshot:
https://ibb.co/jTFc9yH